Playstore subscription upgrade shows error popup
App have play store subscriptions (Monthly and yearly)
user can upgrade (WITH_TIME_PRORATION) monthly to yearly.
In India ,when user upgrade it shows error popup from play store.
Response from Google billing SDK

{
"zza": 5,
"zzb": "The subscription can\u0027t have the first charge for free."
}

billing Library version :v6
